# Structural bolt vs screw question on shed plans

Tags: joists, structural, shed

I'm building a firewood shed from these Popular Mechanics plans https://www.popularmechanics.com/home/how-to-plans/a33943439/how-to-build-a-firewood-shack/. It says to join the short direction joists (B and E) to posts (A and G) using 3" screws. But they support the inner long direction joists (D), which themselves support the floor. Shouldn't they be bolted to the posts like the front and back joists (C) are? If not, why?

**Edit**: the photo at the top of the page appears to show a gap between the concrete block and the front joist. The end joist would be at the same height, therefore not supported by the block either, from what I can see:

[image]

Comment: Can't view the plans without being a member

Comment: Without being able to view the plans, we can't help much here.  Sorry.

Comment: weird, I'm not a member or logged in or anything. maybe it's because I have an ad blocker, so it lets me through

Comment: Is it because they are sitting on the concrete corner post/blocks, so are fully supported?

Plus, bolting into end grain is difficult to do and can easily split the timber (although it can be done and there are several techniques).

Comment: I thought that, but the photo at the top does appear to show some vertical space between the concrete block and the front joist. By bolting into end grain do you mean through the face of the board but close to the end (in this case 1 3/4" from the end)? Otherwise no bolt would need to go through the end of the board

Comment: Without the plans or our ability to get access to them, this will be very difficult to answer. You most likely cannot share the plans here because they're copyrighted and Pop Mech's terms will not permit you to share them, or even screen shots of them.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using an excerpt of the picture to answer the question.  I was able to see it despite others saying it was members only.

[image: Shed Plans]

For a shed resting on deck blocks like this, the joists will rest on the shoulders of the blocks.  Both B and both E boards will be supported on their ends by the deck blocks.  The designers appear to have used bolts on the front to hold up the posts and prevent racking/tilting, and the front is the easiest place to install them.

With lag bolts being installed in the front there's not a lot of room for bolts also coming in from the left and the right, so they went with 3" deck screws.

Comment: I just added a photo to the original post, showing what appears to be clearance between concrete block and front joist, so not supported.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see the gap you're talking about.  I still think the bolts on the front are to stop it from tipping and the screws should be sufficient for E and B.  The floor boards are also supported by the front and back boards that are bolted in so the screw connection isn't holding all of the weight.  Some shims under E and B if they don't touch will help support them if you think its needed.

Comment: If anything, the "short joists" B & E carry more load than the front/back joists, C.  So I don't understand why C would be bolted with carriage bolts, while B & E should be screwed.

Comment: I’m thinking because if the whole unit, which doesn’t have front or back walls, is pushed, it would allow the posts to twist. The heavier bolts will help resist that twisting, which is a potentially high force.  The only force acting on the short joists is some of the weight of the floor.

Comment: this is for firewood, so the floor will need to support a few thousand pounds. not insignificant, so I'm just going to bolt the short joists to be safe. In retrospect, I should have just had the joists resting on the blocks

Comment: @carillonator, just pay attention to the spacing of the bolts.  Don't run them into each other.  I think more bolts is fine, was just trying to explain their choices.